# sorting items in RadListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am having issues with the RadListBox not sorting no idea why. I want to sort by name. I have something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         BindItems();
       }



protected void BindItems()
{
    lstItems.Items.Clear();

    lstItems.DataSource = ItemsAdmin.GetItems();

    lstItems.DataTextField = "Name";
    lstItems.DataValueField = "ItemID";
    lstItems.Sort = RadListBoxSort.Ascending;
    lstItems.SortItems();  
    lstItems.DataBind();       
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you sort the data source by yourself, e.g:

```
lstItems.DataSource = ItemsAdmin.GetItems().OrderBy(item => item.Name);
```

**Update** (re your comment): I'm not familiar with DataTable. Maybe you have to create a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd1cd0a.aspx) then:

```
DataView view = new DataView(ItemsAdmin.GetItems(), "",
    "Name", // sort by Name
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
lstItems.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: Hello, GetItems returns a DataTable, its giving an error that it does not have property OrderBy

Comment: No luck when adding using System.Linq

Comment: @user710502: More luck when using a DataView? (see updated answer)

Comment: Question what happens to to the DataValueField of the RadListBox?